# Structual induction in Haskell

Tags: haskell, induction

Can anyone give me an example of Structural induction in Haskell? I can't find nothing online about it, I have been given a hypothesis but having trouble formulating the base case.

The hypothesis is:
For all lists `xs` of type `[a]` and all `x` of type `a` it is:

```
toLast (x:xs) = xs |++| [x]
```

With `|++|` being my own version of concatenating two lists and `toLast` being a function where the header of a list goes to the end of the list. I have tried to figure this out myself and got `toLast [] = [] |++| []` but I am unsure if this is correct.

Comment: Why not `toLast [] = []`?

Comment: I don’t understand what is being asked. Are you asking for an example of proof via structural induction or are you asking what the definition of `toLast []` should be? If you are being given a question, can you tell us the question itself?

Comment: Nope, I have the definition of toLast, I was looking for an example of proof via structural induction, in particular the base case

Comment: A proof of what? What are you trying to prove?

Comment: Am I clear that the definition of `toLast` is something else besides the code you posted `toLast (x:xs) = xs |++| [x]`, and that code is actually the property you're trying to prove?  It's confusing because it's a valid definition as is.

Comment: Also for using structural induction you need to know some recursive properties of the functions you're using. Can you please include the definition of `toLast` and the definition of `(|++|)`, which then could be used in such a proof?

Comment: "For all ***lists*** `xs`" there's your induction. What is its base case? Is `[1,2]` a list? Is `[1]`?

Comment: `toLast` is not recursive. You can’t do any induction because you aren’t going to need any induction hypothesis. Your function is little different from `data Consoid a b = Nil | Cons a b; toLast Nil = Nil; toLast (Cons a b) = Cons b a`. There is no induction because there is no recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone give me an example of Structural induction in Haskell?

Structural induction always requires two steps:

1. Consider the base cases
2. Consider the generic case by assuming that a function body exists for a list *xs*, and use that assumption to construct a definition for the next step (*x*:*xs*). This is the so called *inductive step*.

Let's use the idea of structural induction to define your `|++|` function, which is a better example in my opinion.

`|++|` takes in two lists and outputs a list that is the concatenation of the first with the second, the type signature is therefore:

```
(|++|) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

The second list input never changes, so we say that the first list is the *parameter of recursion*. The base case is therefore when the first list is empty:

```
(|++|) [] ys = ys
```

Now, lets consider the case when the first argument to `|++|` is not the empty list but is `xs`. The inductive step is to assume that our function `(|++|) xs ys` works (because it is shown to be valid in the base case)  and use that assumption to define the general case when the first input to `|++|` is `(x:xs)`. Putting these together, so far, we have:

```
(|++|) []     ys = ys -- base case
(|++|) (x:xs) ys = let assumedAlreadyConcatenatedList = ((|++|) xs ys) in *something...* assumedAlreadyConcatenatedList -- half-done general case
```

Having assumed that `((|++|) xs ys)` works correctly, we just need to define what to do with `x` and then we are done. How do we concatenate x to a list of already concatenated items? We use cons:

```
(|++|) []     ys = ys -- base case
(|++|) (x:xs) ys = let assumedAlreadyConcatenatedList = ((|++|) xs ys) in x : assumedAlreadyConcatenatedList -- completed general case.
```

Hopefully it's clear that we would always need a base case to back our assumption in the inductive step.